# Entity Framework cascade delete using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table `Products` and another table `ProductDetails`:

```
  CreateTable(
            "dbo.Products",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    // other fields here
                    // ....
                    //....
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ProductType", t => t.ProductTypeId, cascadeDelete: false)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: false)
            .Index(t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.ProductTypeId);

 CreateTable(
            "dbo.ProductDetails",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    // other fields here
                    // ....
                    //....
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)                
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Products", t => t.ProductId, cascadeDelete: false)
            .Index(t => t.ProyectoId)
```

As you can see, when I created this table I disabled `cascadeDelete`. However, after some development I realized I need to delete a product. Now, my problem is that I can not just delete a product by doing something like this

```
 var product = getProductById(Id);
_dbContext.Product.Remove(product);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

How can I do to cascade delete my product table? can I do something like a query for `cascadeDelete`?

```
_dbContext.Product.cascadeDelete...   //this is not real code
```

If it is not possible, how can I alter both my tables `Products` and `ProductDetails`.

Thanks

Comment: Why not enable cascade delete?

Comment: Yeah, why did you disable it if you need it? You can manually delete the related `ProductDetails` before deleting the `Product` records, but that's exactly what delete cascade option is for.

Comment: thanks, how can I enable again cascade delete please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution-1:**

With the existing configuration first you have to delete the `ProductDetails` of the `Product` before deleting the `Product` as follows:

```
List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList =  _dbContext.ProductDetails.Where(pd => pd.ProductId == Id).ToList();
 _dbContext.ProductDetails.RemoveRange(productDetailsList);  

var product = getProductById(Id);
_dbContext.Product.Remove(product);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**Solution-2:**

In your `DbContext` class rewrite the entity configuration as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.Entity<ProductDetails>().HasRequired(pd => pd.Product).WithMany(p => p.ProductDetails).HasForeignKey(pd => pd.ProductId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Now run a new migration and update the database accordingly.

**Hope your problem will be solved!**